# Overflow-y auto in pop up

Tags: html, css

I have a question regarding overflow-y:auto and pop up. I have 2 divs inside a pop up but only on the second one I want to implement some scrolling if needed. The pop up has a max-height so if the second div has a bigger height than the max height of the pop up I would expect to see a scroll. But in fact that is not what happens. The second div just increases to a higher height than the pop up extending to a place out of the pop up. Why does this happen?

This is how it looks like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aryCw.png)

The css:

```
.class1 {
    max-height: 100px;
    
}
```

```
.class2 {
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

The HTML:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvbV0.png)

Comment: Please add HTML, CSS code here, or some demo link like codesandbox or jsfiddle etc for better understanding and it is easy to debug.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the `class2` scroll inside `class1`, you need to add this css inside `class1` (the popup container):

```
      overflow: scroll;
```

Full Code:

```
.class1 {
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
.class2 {
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

For more info [visit: *overflow - css tricks*](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow/)

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the response! I have tried your suggestion but it does not solve my problem, because I get a scroll for the entire div1, while I wanted just the scroll for div2.

Answer (score 0):

1. I found a bug in your code as `class1` is the parent class for `class2`. You set a max height to the parent class, `class 1`. `Class2` has a height of `300px`, which is more significant than the parent class `class1`. So basically the child class is already bigger than the parent class `class1`. When you enter content in the child class that is `class2` it grows more than the height of the parent class that is `class1`. Now the solution code is:

```
.class1 {
  max-height: 300px;
}
    
.class2 {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your response! I have done that on purpose, because I wanted to make a reason for the scroll in the div2 to exist.